# how to setup spark environment?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, bigdata

I am new to both scala and spark and I am using Intellij for running spark application.
It is an helloworld to spark using scala.
I got the code from [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/andyjudson/198b2ff070a483927e82)
and I am getting these errors even after doing setup for spark using maven.

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/11/02 22:31:22 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:192)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2136)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2136)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2136)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:322)
    at HelloWorld$.main(HelloWorld.scala:14)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

I know it is a very simple error, but I tried almost every web-link and still not able to get the solution.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code that you are using  ?

Comment: change the dependancies, for spark 2.0  `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0"`.  spark 1.0 `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0"`

Comment: what is your spark version ?

Comment: Hi, I am using <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: the github link of the code is https://gist.github.com/andyjudson/198b2ff070a483927e82